# Is it possible to activate data-add-back-btn through jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery Mobile 1.3.1, and I have several pages defined like this:

```
<div id="q1" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="false" data-back-btn-text="Home">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
         <h1><Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="info-wrapper"></div>
    <div data-role="content"></div>
</div>
```

The point is that at later time I want to active the back button which is set to false, and change the button text which is set to Home. I want to do them through jQuery code. Is it possible?

Comment: You want to set the `data-add-back-btn` property value to `true` and change the text inside it, is that it..?

Comment: @TJ yes, make it true, and change the btn-text value, but with jQuery code, not directly through HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cant be done this way, as the button should be created during `pagecreate`.

You have two options:

1. Create the button and hide it. Show it when you need it.

   ```
   /* hide it */
   $.mobile.activePage.find(".ui-header [data-rel=back]")
       .addClass("ui-screen-hidden");

   /* show it */
   $.mobile.activePage.find(".ui-header [data-rel=back]")
       .removeClass("ui-screen-hidden");
   ```
2. Add the button dynamically to the page you want.

   ```
   $(document).on('pageinit', "#home", function () {
       $(".foo").on("click", function () { /* you can use any other method */
           /* button */
           var backbtn = '<a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-rel="back">Back</a>';
           /* add it to active page */
           $.mobile.activePage.find(".ui-header")
               .append(backbtn)
               .end()
               .trigger('pagecreate'); /* button won't be created without this */
       });
   });
   ```

   > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/fccf3/)**

Comment: @ett I have modified button's markup. I've missed `data-rel="back"`.